# WPF: Trigger for ListBoxItem.IsSelected not working for Background property

Tags: wpf, background, styles

I try to change the `Background` property for my `ListBoxItem`s using triggers in the `ItemContainerStyle` of my `ListBox` as follows:

```
    <ListBox Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="107,59,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="239">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Lightblue"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.Items>
            <ListBoxItem Content="First Item"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="SecondItem"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Third Item"/>
        </ListBox.Items>
    </ListBox>
```

I would expect unselected items to have a light blue background, hovered items (i.e. when the mouse cursor is over them) to be yellow and selected items to be red.

For the unselected and hovered items this is working as expected, but the selected items still have their standard background color (i.e. blue, if the listbox has focus and light gray otherwise).

Is there anything I'm missing? Is this behaviour documented somewhere?

Thanks for any hint!

**EDIT**

I'm aware of the solution of overriding the default system colors (as described in [Change selected and unfocused Listbox style to not be grayed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698830/wpf-listbox-change-selected-and-unfocused-style-to-not-be-grayed-out), thanks anyway for everyone posting this as an answer). However this is not what I want to do. I'm more interested in why my solution doesn't work.

I'm suspecting the standard `ControlTemplate` of `ListItem` to define it's own triggers which seem to take precendence over triggers defined by the style (perhaps someone could confirm this and point me to some resource where this behaviour is defined).

My solution for the meantime is to define a `ControlTemplate` for my `ListItem`s like:

```
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Border Name="Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="LightBlue" Margin="0">
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: in this meaning you use right solution yet. No solution with standard ControlTemplate and without brush overriding.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A little bit of reflecting on the Aero-style offers us an explanation to why this simple trigger-setting doesn't work.

The ListBoxItem has a ControlTemplate with triggers that takes precedence over our trigger. At least this seems to be true for a MultiTrigger.
I´ve managed to override the simple trigger of Selected=true but for the multitrigger I had to make my own ControlTemplate.

This is the template from the Aero style that shows the problematic MultiTrigger:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static HighlightBrush}}" Property="Background" />
            <Setter Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static HighlightTextBrush}}" Property="Foreground" />
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
                <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static ControlBrush}}" Property="Background" />
            <Setter Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static ControlTextBrush}}" Property="Foreground" />
        </MultiTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static GrayTextBrush}}" Property="Foreground" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Border Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Hope it clears things up a little bit. I can't fathom why they´ve overcomplicated the style this much.

Answer (score 7):

delete IsSelected trigger
And add to listbox:

```
<ListBox.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                         Color="Red" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}"
                         Color="Red" />
</ListBox.Resources>
```

First brush for focused second for otherwise

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this to your window resources -

```
 <Window.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                             Color="Red" />
 </Window.Resources>
```

And remove the IsSelected Trigger from your code, it won't work because every system has its default highlight brush depending on your system theme.

You need to override the highlight brush in your code to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Selector.IsSelected in your Trigger rather than IsSelected.