# Change color of ListBoxItem background when selected and unfocused

Tags: wpf, listbox, focus, listboxitem

I am trying to change the background color of the selected items in a list box. I did that before by using

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Yellow" />
```

which worked. But if I set IsEnabled to false on the ListBox, the whole background of the ListBox turns to the specified color of the ControlBrush. I only want to have the color changed if a ListBoxItem is selected and the ListBox has no focus.

I tried some varieties with triggers, but I can't get it to work. Even a multitrigger containing conditions with IsSelected and IsFocused didn't work for me.

Does anyone have a solution for me?

**Edit:**
Tried the example with the ItemContainerStyle where I am getting a NullReferenceException in my project. In a new solution it works. That's the code where it doesn't work:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Classification.Values}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=ClassificationEnabled}"
                                  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="measureClassificationControl">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="2">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category}"/>
                                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Values.SortedList}" SelectionMode="Extended" Grid.Row="1"  AlternationCount="2" 
                                     SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Height="120">
                                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding Key}">
                                            <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                                                <ToolTip>
                                                     <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                                                </ToolTip>
                                            </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                                        </TextBlock>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListBox>

                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <UniformGrid Columns="2"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `SystemColors.ControlBrushKey` to the `ItemContainerStyle` instead. This way it will only affect the selected items.

**Edit:** Here is a complete Xaml example.

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=enabledButton, Path=IsChecked}">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}"
                                     Color="Yellow" />
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 3</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 4</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 5</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
    <ToggleButton Name="enabledButton" IsChecked="True" Content="IsEnabled"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried out your code but i am getting a NullReferenceException in the InitializeComponent() Method of the control.

Comment: Updated my answer, just paste that into a new solution

Comment: I tried your code and I got no exception. My guess is the exception comes from `ListBox_SelectionChanged`. Try to comment out that code and see if you're still getting the exception

Comment: @flashflail: Any luck? Otherwise, try to remove as much as possible until the exception disappears. Then add it back, step by step, until it comes back. Then you have isolated it and can work out what the problem is.

Comment: As long as your code isn't inside my ItemsControl it works. Do you know why it doesn't work inside the ItemsControl?

Comment: @flashflail: So as soon as you add my addition you get that exception?

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot have both `IsSelected` `True` and `IsEnabled` `False`. Also `IsFocused` `True` and `IsEnabled` `False`.
2. Your question talks about background color change for `IsSelected` as `True` and `IsFocused` as False.

In the code below (just paste `ListBox` XAML in youre Window code)... all these state combinations are achieved ... to check if something is focused but not selected, you would have to select some row and then use "Control + Up / Down Arrow keys" to loose focus from the selected row and focus other non-selected rows.

You will also observe that the `Orange` color for selected row's background would not appear (the `Foreground` color `Cyan` works though). For that background color change you must have to override the [template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361698/wpf-trigger-for-listboxitem-isselected-not-working-for-background-property) of ListBoxItem.

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplicationThemeTest.Window2"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Sample.Controls"
            xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
            Title="Window1">
        <ListBox>
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <!--Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/-->
                                <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="My Value6">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.Resources>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
                    <sys:String>My Value1</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>My Value2</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>My Value3</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>My Value4</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>My Value5</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>My Value6</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>My Value7</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>My Value8</sys:String>
                </x:Array>
            </ListBox.ItemsSource>
        </ListBox>
    </Window>
```

I hope this guides you in correct direction.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried overriding the template like described in the link. But I am getting the error that IsSelectionActive isn't known by ListBoxItem.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the problem now. Problem seemed to be that the XamlParser doesn't like it when the system color is overwritten multiple times. So I defined it like that:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:dg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit" xmlns:DataGridTest="clr-namespace:DataGridTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <DataGridTest:VM />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Values}">
            <ItemsControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Style.Resources>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}"
                                     Color="Yellow" />
                    </Style.Resources>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.Resources>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=enabledButton, Path=IsChecked}">
                        <ListBoxItem>Item 1</ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem>Item 2</ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem>Item 3</ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem>Item 4</ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem>Item 5</ListBoxItem>
                    </ListBox>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        </ItemsControl>
        <ToggleButton Name="enabledButton" IsChecked="True" Content="IsEnabled"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Thanks for your help!