# Dynamic highlight color in ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, dynamic, highlight

How can I make background highlight color dependent on some property of ListViewItem?

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue that people often ask for. Actually, for some reasons, when an item is selected in a ListView or ListBox, the Background color is not the one that is changed. It is a bit more tricky. In fact you need to override the value of the static color resources to which the item template is bound. So to change the higlighting colors of the items you have to do like this:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Orange"/>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</List>
```

Here is a more developed explanation: [Trigger for ListBoxItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361698/wpf-trigger-for-listboxitem-isselected-not-working-for-background-property)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

For changing selected background, you will have to override the ListViewItem's Template.

See this... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788717(v=vs.90).aspx.

Replace the `{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundBrush}` with your preferred background brush in the template.

---

To change backgrounds based on ANY other property that the control template does not rely upon, You can use triggers ...

```
 <ListView ...>
  <ListView.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
     <Style.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="SomeListViewItemProperty" Value="Value1">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
       </Trigger>
       <Trigger Property="SomeListViewItemProperty" Value="Value2">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
       </Trigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
  <ListView.Resources>
 </ListView>
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you, but it isn't answer I looked for :(.I know how to set background for list item. But when I select an item its background still becomes blue (default system highlight brush color). And if I have only one item in the list, I cannot even see its background color because I cannot change selection.