# Why can't I combine these two ListBox features?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, xamlparseexception

In my ListBox I wanted to bind the IsSelected property of each item to my ViewModel, and did so successfully. Then I wanted to make selected items more visible when they don't have keyboard focus, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698830/wpf-listbox-change-selected-and-unfocused-style-to-not-be-grayed-out) told me how to do so. Either feature alone works, but combining them causes the following exception on startup:

**XamlParseException**: A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Value' property of type 'Setter'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Here's my XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="objectList" ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredList}" SelectionMode="Extended">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <!--Make unfocused selected items more visible-->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="LightBlue" Opacity=".5"/>
            </Style.Resources>
            <!-- Support multiselect-->
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Strange, I copy pasted your XAML and I don't get any errors.

Comment: @anivas: thanks, but did you try attaching it to an actual ViewModel? Well, sadly I get this error even if I misspell both bindings.... looks like I just have to settle for a selection background that is almost invisible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried reproducing this in a new, clean, empty project and the error still occurs... if the .NET Framework version is 3.5. However, if I change the .NET Framework version to 4, the error disappears. It's probably a bug in .NET 3.5.

Comment: It's not a bug, i totally overlooked that you could have been using an old version, in 3.5 it's probably handled as in Silverlight.

Comment: What is that supposed to mean? What two features are you talking about?

Comment: As the question says, Feature 1: binding the IsSelected property of each item to my ViewModel. Feature 2: use a Style to make selected items more visible when they don't have keyboard focus.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot reproduce this, that would be an error i would expect in Silverlight but not WPF. In SL you cannot create bindings using Setters.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Is there any way to debug problems in XAML?

Comment: I do not know, i only know how to debug failing bindings; You could upload some project which reliably causes this problem so other people can have a look at it. Unless the problem can be reproduced i for one cannot help you right now i'm affraid.