# How to disable the grey focus on TreeView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change selected and unfocused Listbox style to not be grayed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698830/change-selected-and-unfocused-listbox-style-to-not-be-grayed-out)

I'd only like to keep the blue focus on the treeview and disable the grey focus. How can this be done in WPF?

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve that, you need to replace the **System Control Brush** like following in TreeViewItem's resources:

```
   <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush  x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Blue>"/>
    </Style.Resources>
   </Style>
```