# Focus on unselected listViewitem

Tags: wpf

I have 2 listViews as shown below.
When I select an item in the first listView it gets Highlighted, but when I select an item in the second listView, the first selected item from the first listView losses its highlightning. I dont want this to happen, I want both items to be highlighted. Any help?

```html
<ListView x:Name="listViewDevice" ItemsSource="{Binding NotMappedInputAttributes}" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="6" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedInputAttribute}" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5,27,5,32" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="150">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Type" Width="150">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TypeName}"/>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Device" Width="150">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding HostDevice.SimulationMemberName}"/>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Text="{Binding SearchColumns, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="5,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Top" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="0" Grid.Row="1" />
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox_Copy" Text="{Binding SearchInputAttributes, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="5" Margin="5,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="2" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <ListView x:Name="treeViewCsvFiles" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" ItemsSource="{Binding CsvColumns}" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" Margin="5,27,5,32" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCsvColumn}" Grid.Row="1">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="File">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding File.Name}"/>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Time Column">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsTimeColumn, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382006/wpf-listview-inactive-selection-color) and this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698830/change-selected-and-unfocused-listbox-style-to-not-be-grayed-out). Some people had the same problem as you have now.

Comment: I tried the given solutions but none of them is working.