# Listview selection color

Tags: wpf, listview, selection, listviewitem

I'm playing around with wpf and I saw the following article:
[WPF ListView Inactive Selection Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382006/wpf-listview-inactive-selection-color)

I want to do something similar. I want to put a border around an a listviewitem when it is selected and i want to not change the background color. The reason I want this is I want a color coded listview and I still want to see the color when it's selected, but i want to know it's selected by it having a border around it.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I tried the below answer and it got me half way, it does put a border around the listviewitem but it overrides my background color. I can't get the right syntax i tried(Notice the BasedOn):

```
    <Style x:Key="SourceListView" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding SourceType, Converter={StaticResource SourceGroupConverter}}"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="MyListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource SourceListView}" >
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Border
                             x:Name="Border"
                             BorderBrush="Transparent"
                             BorderThickness="1">
                        <GridViewRowPresenter Columns="{TemplateBinding GridView.ColumnCollection}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I then tried this:

```
    <Style x:Key="MyListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding SourceType, Converter={StaticResource SourceGroupConverter}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            ...//Same as above
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Both attempts just set the background to white(or transparent I don't know). I know it's just syntax and I'd appreciate another nudge in the right direction :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the ItemContainerStyle on the ListView to a style that doesn't change the background when an item is selected but instead changes the color of a border. Below is an example:

```
  <Style x:Key="MyListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding SourceType, Converter={StaticResource SourceGroupConverter}}" />
     <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
           <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
              <Border
                 x:Name="Border"
                 BorderBrush="Transparent"
                 BorderThickness="1"
                 Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                 <GridViewRowPresenter Columns="{TemplateBinding GridView.ColumnCollection}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
              </Border>
              <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                 <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                 </Trigger>
              </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
           </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
  </Style>
```

And then use the style like this:

```
<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyListViewItemStyle}">
   ...
</ListView>
```

Comment: I tried this and it did set a border, but it seems my syntax for the background color is being overridden. Any more help? Another thing i noticed is that the listview only gets selected if you click a non-whitespace area(e.g. click the content of a column) of the listviewitem with the above style. Why is this?

Comment: I updated my code example. I added a TemplateBinding to the Background property of the border to the background property of the ListViewItem. I don't know why it's behaving like you're explaining with the selection. I've tried my example and I can click on an empty space on a row and still select it.