# ListViewitem background color not changing on selection

Tags: wpf

I have a ListView...and I am overriding the template of listview item to add a border to it.

But, when I do that - while selecting an item in listview ...the background is not getting changed to blue(as it do normally).

Do I need to add TemplateBinding for background color ? Please help me.

```
<ListView.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType='{x:Type ListViewItem}'>
          <Border DataContext="{Binding Item.Type}" Style="{StaticResource   ValidationResultBorderStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          <GridViewRowPresenter  />
         </Border>
       </ControlTemplate>
     </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
   </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we override the `Template` of any item containers, we should maintain their behaviors from their default template... To do that we must maintain their content presenters and triggers etc...

These articles may help you...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/8d849ee7-a502-445e-bb77-aa00a2e59982

[Listview selection color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895309/listview-selection-color)