# WPF datagrid - how to stop the cell being selected when a child control is selected

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, focus

I'm pretty new to WPF so be kind...

I am placing a number of child controls into a DataGrid cell, however when I select (click on) one of the child controls the containing cell shows the blue selection highlight. Is there a way to change this functionality so it just selects the control that was clicked on.

I expect I could get around this by changing the selection colour to transparent or something, but the selection does more change the appearance, if the user then hits the ArrowDown key I want the selection to move from the control I consider to be selected not the cell that DataGrid thinks is selected.

Ideally I want to manage all the selection and navigation within the DataGrid.

[image]

In the example I would the control containing Neil9232 to be selected

Comment: If worse comes to worst, you could probably do this with an `ItemsControl` instead of a `DataGrid`. Here's one idea with the DataGrid, though: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2502523/424129

Answer (score 1):

In your CellTemplate, set `Focusable` to false.  It will stop snatching your clicks. For example, if you don't currently have a Style set, this would be the bare minimum:

```
 <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="NotFocusable" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource NotFocusable}"/>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>                    
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Great, that's killed off pretty much all the data grids built in mouse and keyboard interaction. Ill have a go at building that functionality back using my own handlers. I'm starting to think the dataGrid is not entirely the right control for this, I need the basic grid layout and the row virtualisation, any suggestions before I push on?

Comment: You could use a handler to focus to an inner child control on double-clicking the cell, for example. Or use a handler to handle selecteditem changes and focus to an inner control. Or you could use `IEditableObject.BeginEdit`, trigger a property change in your viewmodel, and bind a trigger to set focusable.