# How to remove WPF ListView Highlight color?

Tags: .net, wpf, styles

I have a list view for which I defined a custom style for the `ItemContainerStyle` which changes the background color of the item for certain value.

The thing is, once I click the listview, an item is selected and it takes a style which I cannot change.

What I would like to do, is just to increase the `BorderThickness`of the `ListViewItem`.

Here is a sample of my `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<Style x:Key="colorStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"></Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Level}" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Indigo"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Level}" Value="2">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Level}" Value="3">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Cyan"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Level}" Value="4">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Level}" Value="5">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Level}" Value="6">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Level}" Value="7">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF ListView turn off selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051215/wpf-listview-turn-off-selection)

Comment: the Trigger on IsSelect doesn't change anything for me. It's really the HighlightColor (gray-blue) that I want to remove.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this? blindmeis' solution does not work here.

Answer (score 3):

one way is to override the systemcolor to get what you want.

```
<ListView>
 <ListView.Resources>
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="DarkGreen"/>
 </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```