# ScrollViewer changes Size of Content(ItemControl) instead of showing a scrollbar

Tags: c#, wpf, size, scrollviewer

I have a WPF UserControl containing an `ItemsControl` with a Horizontal `StackPanel` as `ItemsPanel` (Basically  some kind of the WinRT Hub Control). And the content extends the Size of the UserControl

If I try to add a `ScrollViewer` around my `ItemsControl`, the `ScrollViewer` shrinks the `ItemsControl` so all Items fit into the UserControl bounds.

Thats somehow exactly the opposite of what i expected can anybody tell me why the scrollviewer behaves this way?

Here is my `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ContentModule.ContentView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             xmlns:contentModule="clr-namespace:ContentModule"
             xmlns:regions="http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF"
             xmlns:statics="clr-namespace:Infrastructure.Statics;assembly=Infrastructure"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance contentModule:ContentViewModel}"
             VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <ItemsControl regions:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static statics:ContentRegions.ContentCollection}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
</UserControl>
```

The Items are injected via Prism RegionManager.

EDIT1:

The `UserControl` is getting Injected into my MainForm. It is assigned to the `ContrentControl` => ShellRegions.Content (the third one)

```
  <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" cal:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static statics:ShellRegions.MainMenu}" />
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" cal:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static statics:ShellRegions.NavigationBar}" />
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="2" cal:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static statics:ShellRegions.Content}" />
    </Grid>
```

EDIT 2: 
Some more details.

The `ItemsControl` looks like :[image: this] (Gray is the `UserControl`, Orange are the items in the `ItemsControl`)
The Content scales when changing the bounds of the `Form`/`UserControl` as expected but the `ItemsControl` does not show a `ScrollBar`.
If i add a `ScrollViewer` the Content does not scale with changing bounds anymore and is Vertically scrollable instead of horizontal, or it does change the width of the items to fit the `UserControll` depending on the `ScrollBar` properties.

But i can't get it working to keep the scaling and add a scroll bar to the bottom of the `ItemsControl`.

Comment: Hi, use a ListBox. :) Why does everybody like ItemsControl. Its actually pretty dump. See it cant event virtualize items, hehe. ListBix is true bad ass.

Comment: could you show the placement of the user control in your window ?

Comment: @devhedgehog I tried changing it but i don't wan't to be able to select my items, so ListBox needs other actions. I actually want to stay with the ItemsControl.

Comment: @console You can disable selection in ListBox thought scrolling and virtualization stays. Those things you will not be able to have when using simple ItemsControl. Check this link out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051215/wpf-listview-turn-off-selection

Comment: @devhedgehog as i mentioned above the listBox doesn't fit my needs even if a disable the selection, there are things that remain (click brings an item to focus etc..)

Comment: Ok let me post you an actual answer to this. I think I get you now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day full of research i found a working solution:

```
<ItemsControl regions:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static statics:ContentRegions.ContentCollection}">
            <ItemsControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Template>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing following:

Wrap your control in a ScrollViewer and set CanContentScrol property to TRUE.

Futhermore change the Panel of your ItemsControl to VirtualizingStackPanel.

```
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

Tell us whether it worked or what kind of new issues those changes will bring up.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't help either i will add a detailed description

Comment: I dont see your ScrollViewer. Where is it?