# When I set the ListBox SelectionMode to "None", it doesn't react to DataSource changes

Tags: c#, listbox

while searching for an answer, I found out it's an old "bug" in VS !(?) I am using VS2013. I simply don't believe that they didn't correct it, so I have to think it's intentional, or there's something I am not doing right...

I want to use ListBox to dislpay some simple results. I want that list to be read-only, items not selectable and so on. Just a display of a simple array of results.

I use an array as a datasource (lstBox.DataSource = somearray;), which I update by setting DataSource to null, then back to somearray. The problem is - if I set the listBox SelectionMode to "none", list gets stuck and it doesn't refresh anymore. I can't refresh it. If I set list as "disabled" instead, it's showing the results correctly, it's not selectable, no matter what SelectionMode says, but it's all greyed out... Any help on this ?

p.s. from what I've read, even setting datasource to BindingList or BindingSource doesn't rectify this problem...

Comment: You, probably, will have to override the ControTemplate for `ListBox` to avoid `IsEnabled` greying - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751990/how-to-change-disabled-background-color-of-textbox-in-wpf. You can get the original template from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754242(v=vs.110).aspx) . Also, nearly duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051215/wpf-listview-turn-off-selection.

Answer (score 0):

SelectionMode [does not have a `None` value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in WPF. (although [it had in WinForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.selectionmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

In WPF, if you want to present items without allowing selection, you should use the [`ItemsControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class instead of the `ListBox`.

But I'm not sure whether you are using **WPF** or **WinForms** by reading your question.

Comment: WinForms, ad yes, there is still possible to have selection set as none in Forms... Sadly I am not using WPF but more and more I see it's advantage as I learn c#...

Comment: Then you should remove the **wpf** tag from your question

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this by setting the selection mode to "One" in the "formclosing" event.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.