# Disable ListView selection and hover

Tags: wpf, listview, itemcontainerstyle

Usually I can disable ListView selection doing like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051215/wpf-listview-turn-off-selection) thread suggests - or something similar where you set the ItemContainerStyle.

However I have this ListView that is defined like this:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding List, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Style="{StaticResource header}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <!-- Some data -->
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridViewColumn>
                ...
            </GridView> 
        </ListView.View>    
    </ListView> 
</ScrollViewer>
```

And if I try to specify the ItemContainerStyle - the data in the list just disappears.

Giving the above ListView, how would I proceed just to removed the selection?

Comment: If there is only one column, and the list should not be selectable, why don't you just use an ItemsControl?

Comment: Right my bad in the above example, there are more than one column. But you are probably right that a simple ItemsControl would be more simple/better because there is nothing to select. It is just a list of information.. I'll try that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this `ItemContainerStyle`? This basically will not pick up any input events.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding List, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}">
            <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```