# Selected item loses style when focus moved out in WPF ListBox

Tags: wpf, listbox, styles

**What do I have?**

I have a `ListBox` populated with items from an XML file. Given a `DynamicResource` for `Style` property and written trigger for `IsSelected` in `ItemContainerStyle`.

**What do I want to do?**

I want to keep the selected Item highlighted even after focus moved out of the `ListBox`.

**What problem am I facing?**

When I select an item the style specified in `IsSelected` trigger works. But, when I move the focus out of list box (press tab or click on some other control) the selected item loses its style. Is there any way so that I can retain the selected item style?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oops!! it was by mistake. Sorry!

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same problem and tried the solution posted but I can't solve the problem. Can you edit your post so it contains the solution? thanks

Comment: @jpsstavares try the second solution (the more popular, but yet not accepted one) -- it works, and won't screw up other WPF UI Elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only setting the background color, try replacing `ControlBrush` for the ListBox, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382006/wpf-listview-inactive-selection-color/382162#382162).

Comment: Ok. Let me try it out. Thanks!

Comment: This is a bad idea -- for users with visual theming turned off, this will mess up a lot of things -- the scroll bars and buttons will change to become the current highlight color (this is blue by default -- so your inner buttons and ListView scrollbars turn blue, very bad!).

Answer (score 37):

[The answer referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1462290/3195477) will in some cases solve the problem, but is not ideal as it breaks when the control is disabled/readonly and it also overrides the color schemes, rather than taking advantage of them. My suggestion is to add the following in the ListBox tags:

```
<ListBox....>
    <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Border Name="Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background"
                                            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

What this will do is set the Highlight background color on the list box item whenever it is selected (regardless of the control state).

My answer is based on help from the answers already given to these answers, along with the following blog: http://blogs.vbcity.com/xtab/archive/2009/06/29/9344.aspx

Comment: Archived blog post: https://web.archive.org/web/20130508120312/http://blogs.vbcity.com/xtab/archive/2009/06/29/9344.aspx