# How to set a WPF ListView Selected Item color?

Tags: wpf, listview, styles, background-color, listviewitem

I am trying to recreate the Mail UI from Windows 8 in a WPF application running on Windows 7. Here's what I want to achieve:

[image: Target UI]

In particular, I don't know how to change the background color for selected items e.g. the Inbox item in the first column and the mail from Twitter in the second column. I have tried several solutions from other similar Stackoverflow Questions but none seem to work for me. e.g.

[Selected item loses style when focus moved out in WPF ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462232/selected-item-loses-style-when-focus-moved-out-in-wpf-listbox)

[WPF ListView Inactive Selection Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382006/wpf-listview-inactive-selection-color/382162#382162)

Here is the code I have for my listview:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedArea}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Areas}" Background="#DCE3E5" >

                    <ListView.Resources>

                        <!-- Template that is used upon selection of an Area -->
                        <ControlTemplate x:Key="SelectedTemplate" TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Border Background="#388095" Cursor="Hand" >
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5" />
                            </Border>                                
                        </ControlTemplate>

                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>                                        
                                    <!-- Base Template that is replaced upon selection -->
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                        <Border Background="#DCE3E5" Cursor="Hand"  >
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5" />
                                        </Border>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SelectedTemplate}" />
                                </MultiTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>

                    </ListView.Resources>                        

                </ListView>
```

How can I change the background color of the selected item? And how do I retain the color change when the focus changes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I did something similar to this recently:

```
<ListView.Resources>                
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="SelectedTemplate" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray" Background="#FF92C6F9" Padding="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" Tag="{Binding Value}" Cursor="Hand" MouseUp="Border_MouseUp_1">                        
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5" />
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray" Background="WhiteSmoke" Padding="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" Tag="{Binding Value}" Cursor="Hand" MouseUp="Border_MouseUp_1" >                                    
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="true" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>                            
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SelectedTemplate}" />                            
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```

I believe removing:

```
<Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="true" />
```

will allow you to keep the background color after focus is lost.

**EDIT:**

In response to your question below:

You can bind the tag property of the TextBlock to the command parameter, and then execute the command on the MouseUp event of the TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" Text="Click Me!" Tag="{Binding MyCommandParameter}" MouseUp="MyTextBlock_MouseUp" />
```

And in the code behind:

```
    private void MyTextBlock_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock tb = sender as TextBlock;

        if (tb != null && tb.Tag != null)
        {
            ViewModel.MyCommand.Execute(tb.Tag);
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @TrueEddie. My machine is acting up and I am not able to test your solution. I will get back as soon as I am able to fix my machine.

Comment: This shows the selection properly. But now that we are using TextBlock instead of the hyperlink I was using, I am no longer able to supply the Command that I needed to invoke. How can I supply the command and associated parameter? When I replace your Border element with hyperlink, it allows me to change color when clicked outside the hyperlink but doesn't let me invoke the command. When I click the hyperlink, it allows me to inovke the command but the color isn't changed.

Comment: The edits didn't work for me but I was able to bind the ListView SelectedItem to a Dependency Property I created in my MVVM model and load the next listview on the change of this property. This removed the need for the hyperlink and I already got the background color from your code. So, now I have the complete solution. Thanks so much for your help. I am posting the final ListView in my question in a few minutes.

Answer (score 10):

Just adding to "TrueEddie" point.

The other option would be "ItemContainerStyle" in ListView.

```
  <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 


                  BorderThickness="0" 
                     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewSmartNotes}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSmartNotes, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding LstSmartNotes, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                  ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ListViewItemOptionStyle}">


        </ListView>
```

ListViewItemOptionStyle defined in Style.xml

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemOptionStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <!-- Trun off default selection-->
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter 
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Fore more details

https://sites.google.com/site/greateindiaclub/mobil-apps/windows8/wpfimportantbindings

Comment: I believe your **ItemContainerStyle** and **ItemTemplate** bindings are reversed and should read `ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemOptionStyle}"`, else you will get a conversion exception. Also, it may be just me, I would recommend using `<GridViewRowPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />` over using `<ContentPresenter />`, if there are multiple columns involved.