# How do I change the color of the item focus rectangle on a WPF ListView? (not the item highlight color)

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

How do I change the color of the item focus rectangle on a WPF ListView?

It's the color of the **focus** rectangle I mean to change, not the color of the selected item (which is green).

See image:
[image]

Comment: already answered , hope this is you are looking.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838524/how-to-set-a-wpf-listview-selected-item-color

Comment: no that topic you talk about is about changing the background color... I know how to do that. I want to change the focus rectangle color.

Comment: You would need to change the style of the focus visual (the focus visual style itself being a property of the ItemContainerStyle). Here is an example of how to manipulate the focus visual style when using a listbox, but it should give you a guidance and insight of how you can do it in your case: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/94b33a20-3d8e-4e13-aca5-76547509978c/how-to-change-the-focus-visual-style-of-a-listbox-thats-using-a-datatemplate?forum=wpf

Comment: @elgonzo You win ;-) post it as an answer so I can give your credit please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the appearance of the focus visual of an item in the *ListView*, you will have to manipulate the `FocusVisualStyle` that is part of the `ItemContainerStyle` used by the *ListView*.

To illustrate, here is a simple example that turns the focus visual into a red dashed (dotted line) rectangle:

```
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <!-- This is the style used by the item container of this ListView -->
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle">
                <Setter.Value>

                    <!-- This is the style for the focus visual -->
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Rectangle SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                                               Stroke="Red"
                                               StrokeThickness="1"
                                               StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>

                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```