# Keeping a listviewitem highlighted when control loses focus

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, listviewitem

I have created tab functionality from a listview. The problem I'm having is that the selected item loses focus when I click away from the control. I want the selected item to stay highlighted so the user knows which tab (listviewitem) they are currently on.

Side note: I am using MaterialDesign for styling.

Here is my code:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvTabs"
    ItemsSource="{Binding tabItems}" ItemTemplate=" 
    {StaticResource TabListViewItemTemplate}">

                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selected item loses style when focus moved out in WPF ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462232/selected-item-loses-style-when-focus-moved-out-in-wpf-listbox)

Comment: I've already seen that question and it hasn't helped me unfortunately. Also, that's a listbox, I'm using a listview. @MikeH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand what you requested. My proposed solution is:
Resources:

```
  <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="ItemStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                            <Border Name="Border" 
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                  Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

   <DataTemplate x:Key="TabListViewItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

And the ListView:

```
 <ListView x:Name="lvTabs" Width="100" Height="200"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              ItemsSource="{Binding }" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TabListViewItemTemplate}"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemStyle}" >

        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
```

I added an array of strings to test the solution.

```
 this.DataContext = new string[] { "Tab1", "Tab2" };
```

It should work with any DataTemplate, as it changes the background only.

Answer (score 0):

The ListView will loose the focus when someother control has the focus. It cannot be avoided. 
But you can change the color of the ListView selected item when it does not have focus
You need to set the color of the ListView selected item not focused.
Just set the inactive selection color which will highlight the listview selected item when it looses focus.

```
<ListView.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
       <Style.Resources>
           <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
       </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</<ListView.Style>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but I paste it into my listview and nothing changes.

Comment: Instead of ListView can you try to use ListBox.

Comment: I'd rather not. Why would that make a difference anyway?

Comment: It works in the Listbox. Or just try to add the code in ListView Style

Answer (score 0):

Based on MaterialDesign ^^ the key is to change IsSelected property instead of IsFocused

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignListBoxItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#DDDDDD"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="100"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="160"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value=" 15 0 0 0"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#333"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFD610"></Setter>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"></Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>


            <ListBoxItem>listbox item 1</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>listbox item 2</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>listbox item 3</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>listbox item 4</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>listbox item 5</ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
```