# Change WinForms' ListView selected and unfocused highlight color

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I want to set the highlight color for a ListViewItem to be the same color as if the ListView is currently in focus even though it isn't.

After setting the HideSelection property to False, when I selected an item and then focusing on another view, the color is grayed out. I want to disable this.

How can I do this?

Similar to this WPF-related question (including screenshots to demonstrate): [WPF ListView Inactive Selection Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382006/wpf-listview-inactive-selection-color)

Comment: if it's similar to the code in the link.. why don't you follow the same concept.. what;s the issue..are you familiar with using the debugger to inspect the properties and change them in the quickwatch editor

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since Windows Forms ListView doesn't have `SelectionBackColor` or such property (as far as I know) I think the most simple way is:

Setting the [`HideSelection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.hideselection?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property of the listview to `true` and then:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
        .ToList().ForEach(item =>
        {
            item.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
            item.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
        });
    this.listView1.SelectedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>()
        .ToList().ForEach(item =>
        {
            item.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
            item.ForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
        });
}
```

Comment: This is awesome. Was just googling and found this. Thanks!! It should be noted though that if you are already formatting a listview with various colors that this will override those line item colors unless you add more code to keep those in place.

Answer (score 8):

Same idea as Reza but more efficient:

```
private void uxListViewTest_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.IsSelected) {
        e.Item.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
        e.Item.ForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
    }
    else {
        e.Item.BackColor = BackColor;
        e.Item.ForeColor = ForeColor;
    }
}
```