# ListBox IsEnabled

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a WPF Listbox with `AlternationCount=2`.
I want to disable selection of the items in the box, but I want to keep the colors.

When I set `IsEnabled="False"` selection of the items in the listbox is disabled but the text and the background becomes gray.

How can I disable selection but keep the foreground color and alternation background color as if it was enabled?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382006/wpf-listview-inactive-selection-color

Comment: Where is your sample code?

Comment: @aengas, can you please give any feedback to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of properties in `ListBoxItem` which might help: `Focusable` and `IsHitTestVisible`. Set one of them to `false` to disable selection from view. (with `Focusable="false"` ListBoxItems will change color on mouse over). Setting `IsEnabled="false"` also prevents selection, but it additionally changes foreground color.

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
            <!--<Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>-->
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

note that selection still can be set by code using ListBox properties: e.g. `SelectedIndex="3"`